# hyperref to sublistings

Tags: hyperref, subcaption, minted

I'm using the `subcaption` package to define sublistings that I can put in my listing float environments. The listing float is defined by `minted`.

This has all been working well so far (see full code example below).

However, when I want to turn my references into hyperlinks with `hyperref`, the sublisting references fail with errors like this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... \Hy@tempb {sublisting.\theHlisting 
                                                  .1}\ifx \Hy@tempa \ltx@emp...
l.33 Here are references to Lst.~\ref{lst:foo}
                                              , Lst.~\ref{lst:bar}, and
```

It seems that there is some interaction between the packages that I don't understand. What do I need to do to get `hyperref` references to sublistings?

---

Self-contained example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted} % Defines the listing float
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{listing} % Allow sublistings
\usepackage{hyperref} % Including this breaks compilation

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
  \begin{sublisting}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{minted}{Python}
      def foo():
          pass 
    \end{minted}
    \caption{First function.}
    \label{lst:foo}
  \end{sublisting}\hfill%
  \begin{sublisting}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{minted}{Python}
      def bar():
          pass 
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Second function.}
    \label{lst:bar}
  \end{sublisting}
  \caption{Two functions.}
  \label{lst:foobar}
\end{listing}

Here are references to Lst.~\ref{lst:foo}, Lst.~\ref{lst:bar}, and
Lst.~\ref{lst:foobar}.

\end{document}
```

(needs `pygmentize` to be installed. Compile with `latexmk -shell-escape -pdf`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the missing command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted} % Defines the listing float
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{listing} % Allow sublistings
\usepackage{hyperref} % Including this breaks compilation
\newcommand\theHlisting{\arabic{listing}}
\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
  \begin{sublisting}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{minted}{Python}
      def foo():
          pass
    \end{minted}
    \caption{First function.}
    \label{lst:foo}
  \end{sublisting}\hfill%
  \begin{sublisting}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{minted}{Python}
      def bar():
          pass
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Second function.}
    \label{lst:bar}
  \end{sublisting}
  \caption{Two functions.}
  \label{lst:foobar}
\end{listing}

Here are references to Lst.~\ref{lst:foo}, Lst.~\ref{lst:bar}, and
Lst.~\ref{lst:foobar}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Can you explain what happens when importing `hyperref` that causes this issue?

Comment: minted creates the listing environment with the (old) float package which doesn't prepare counters for hyperref, the newer subcaption does it for the subcounter, but doesn't check if the `\theH...` definition for the main counter exists, and so the definition is missing.